# Scala List Transformation to Map

Tags: scala

Can someone help me getting below O/P using Scala

```
Input : List((1,"a1"),(1,"a2"),(1,"a3"),(2,"b1"),(2,"b2"),(2,"b3"))

OutPut: Map((1,("a1","a2","a3")),(2,("b1","b2","b3")))
```

Comment: Hi Xavier,
Thanks for quick response
above line gives me below output
Map((1,List("a1","a2","a3")),(2,List("b1","b2","b3")))

I dont want values to be List. Those must be Tuple

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follows:

```
l.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2)).mapValues((elem => (elem(0), elem(1), elem(2))))
```

`groupBy` will get you a map with the key and the whole list as value.

`mapValues` will map every list for each key.

the inner `map` will retrieve only the second element of each Tuple of the List

the second `mapValues` will convert your List to Tuple

**Result**:

```
l.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2)).mapValues((elem => (elem(0), elem(1), elem(2))))
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,(String, String, String)] = Map(2 -> (b1,b2,b3), 1 -> (a1,a2,a3))
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick Response S Couto. It worked for me.

Comment: Glad to help @BharathKumar . Feel free to upvote or accept the answer so other users with similar questions can find it

Answer (score 1):

With grouping and map, you can go from List[(Int, String)]:

```
scala> val li = List((1,"a1"),(1,"a2"),(1,"a3"),(2,"b1"),(2,"b2"),(2,"b3"))
li: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a1), (1,a2), (1,a3), (2,b1), (2,b2), (2,b3))
```

to a Map[Int,List[String]]:

```
scala> li.groupBy (_._1).map {case (k, l) => (k, l.map {_._2})}
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(2 -> List(b1, b2, b3), 1 -> List(a1, a2, a3))
```

but note, that it is a Map from Int to List (String), not to a Tuple3 of String.

To build a Tuple, you might do:

```
scala> li.groupBy (_._1).map {case (k, ll) => (k, ll.map {_._2})}.map {case (k, l) => (k, (l(0), l(1), l(2)))}
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,(String, String, String)] = Map(2 -> (b1,b2,b3), 1 -> (a1,a2,a3))
```

Comment: Cant we make it a Tuple3??

Comment: Well, yes, we can.

Comment: Can you help me how to do it